# Missing right parenthesis error in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Following query working fine in SQL Server 2012. But when I try to run it on Oracle it gives **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.** Can not figure out what I did wrong here.

```
SELECT p1.ACTION_ID,
       STUFF( (SELECT ',  '+EMP_DISPLAY_NAME
               FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
                      FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
                      LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP
                          ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
                      LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS
                          ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID) p2
               WHERE p2.ACTION_ID = p1.ACTION_ID
               ORDER BY EMP_DISPLAY_NAME
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
            ,1,3,'')
       AS NAME
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
       FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
       LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP
           ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
       LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS
           ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID) p1
GROUP BY ACTION_ID
```

Comment: Should'nt you use || instead of + when concating strings in oracle? `',  '+EMP_DISPLAY_NAME`

Comment: Have you counted the ( and ) respectively?

Comment: @President Camacho Actually I'm using Toad, not give any error with +.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, running fine in SQL Server

Comment: Can you try break down every subquery and run them independently?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho: actually `||` is not specific to Oracle. It's the string concatenation operator that has been defined in the SQL standard nearly 30 years ago.

Comment: + highlighted  as an operator in Toad

Comment: @Nishantha: `+` is indeed a valid operator in SQL - but it's only for **numbers** (e.g. `40 + 2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query I concluded minimal data structure:

```
HS_HR_OB_ACTION (action_id number)
HS_HR_EMPLOYEE (EMP_NUMBER number, emp_display_name varchar2(20))
HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT (ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER number, action_id number)
```

For such data following query works in Oracle 10g. For Oracle 11 uncomment second line and comment third line. Please compare results with SQL Server.

```
SELECT p1.ACTION_ID,
    -- (select LISTAGG(emp_display_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emp_display_name)
    (SELECT wmsys.wm_concat(EMP_DISPLAY_NAME)
       FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
           FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
             LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
             LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
         ) p2
       WHERE p2.ACTION_ID = p1.ACTION_ID) AS NAME
  FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
      FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
        LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
        LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
    ) p1
  GROUP BY ACTION_ID
```

---

I think this query may be yet simplified, but I didn't want to interfere too much in original version at first.

```
SELECT distinct ACTION_ID, wmsys.wm_concat(EMP_DISPLAY_NAME) -- or listagg(...)
  FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
    LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
  GROUP BY ACTION_ID
```

Comment: Thanks @Ponder Stibbons. These queries are working well with small modification for me. LISTAGG not supported in my version and wmsys.wm_concat worked fine.

Comment: This `ORDER BY EMP_DISPLAY_NAME FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')` was invalid syntax for Oracle. It expected scalar value here. Also Oracle has not `stuff` function and concatenation should be `||` instead of `+`, but it was not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT ',  '+EMP_DISPLAY_NAME

It is not a valid Oracle syntax. You need to use the concatenation operator `||`

For example, `SELECT EMP_DISPLAY_NAME||' ,'`

Test case -

```
SQL> SELECT 'Employee ID is '||empno FROM emp;

'EMPLOYEEIDIS'||EMPNO
----------------------------------------------
Employee ID is 7369
Employee ID is 7499
Employee ID is 7521
Employee ID is 7566
Employee ID is 7654
Employee ID is 7698
Employee ID is 7782
Employee ID is 7788
Employee ID is 7839
Employee ID is 7844
Employee ID is 7876
Employee ID is 7900
Employee ID is 7902
Employee ID is 7934

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried this and don't think this is my case + does not give any error. Query always stops at ORDER BY

Comment: It will definitely throw an error. Perhaps there are other errors too, once you fix them then you would see an error due to concatenation syntax too.

Comment: @Nishantha, Oracle doesn't parse the query in sequence before returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Little modifications I did for Ponder Stibbons answer to work with me because they gave **CLOB** error. Thanks @Ponder Stibbons.

```
SELECT p1.ACTION_ID,
    -- (select LISTAGG(emp_display_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emp_display_name)
    (SELECT dbms_lob.substr( wmsys.wm_concat(EMP_DISPLAY_NAME), 4000, 1 ) 
       FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
           FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
             LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
             LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
         ) p2
       WHERE p2.ACTION_ID = p1.ACTION_ID) AS NAME
  FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT EMP.EMP_DISPLAY_NAME,ACTS.ACTION_ID
      FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
        LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
        LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
    ) p1
  GROUP BY ACTION_ID
```

This also working fine.

```
  SELECT distinct ACTS.ACTION_ID, dbms_lob.substr( wmsys.wm_concat(EMP_DISPLAY_NAME), 4000, 1 )
  FROM HS_HR_OB_ACT_ALT_RECIPIENT ALT
    LEFT JOIN HS_HR_EMPLOYEE EMP ON EMP.EMP_NUMBER=ALT.ACTALT_EMP_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN HS_HR_OB_ACTION ACTS ON ACTS.ACTION_ID=ALT.ACTION_ID
  GROUP BY ACTS.ACTION_ID
```